# PowerBook G4 (No Intel) running OS X 10.4.11 (Tiger) doesn't react to clicks from the touchpad or mouse ...

Tags: mouse, trackpad, macos

My PowerBook G4 (without Intel) running OS X 10.4.11 (Tiger) doesn't react to clicks from the touchpad or mouse ... any ideas why? and what to do? Is it a Software or Hardware issue? Don't have a OS X Tiger CD to reinstall. Did check what I could on SafeBoot, at some point it said that the HD seems functioning correctly.

Any solution for this? Any informed ideas would be greatly appreciate it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a USB mouse and the mac is still not responding to you, then its clearly a software issue. I would recommend you to using your installer disk and clean install the OS, this will surely fix the issue.

Comment: My laptop didn't arrived with an Installer CD ...  ):  Where could I find one? It's an old OS X 10.4.11 - Tiger

Comment: @Hill You can install leopard on your G4. If you don't have a disk, no issues. Reboot and go to recovery (cmd+R) and use internet recovery option.